# Why MessageBox isn't showing?

Tags: c#, windows

Why Message Box in WPF isn't showing?
I have no any errors.
Names from XAML file are correct, so I don't know what's going on.

Please help me guys!
I don't know what should I change.
Thanks for help!

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Label x:Name="label" Content="App" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="214,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="33" Width="89"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="loginBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="214,54,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <PasswordBox x:Name="passwordBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="214,92,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Label x:Name="log" Content="Login:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="167,51,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label x:Name="pass" Content="Password:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="146,86,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button x:Name="log_in" Content="LOG IN" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="279,117,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication2
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void log_in_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            string login = loginBox.Text;
            string password = passwordBox.Password;

            if(check(login, password)){
                MessageBox.Show("Welcome!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong login or password!");
            }

        }

        public bool check(string login, string password)
        {
            if(login == "admin" && password == "123")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How do you call `log_in_Click`? Can we see the XAML for that?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/09SZhS3n

Comment: Put in the question please.

Comment: Please paste the XAML into your question. Not the pastebin link. The XAML.

Comment: Missing the onclick event on xaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never call `log_in_Click`. WPF won't guess from the name that you want to associate it with the button. You have to explicitly make it the button's click handler, like so:

```
<Button 
    Click="log_in_Click"

    x:Name="log_in" 
    Content="LOG IN" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="279,117,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="75"
    />
```